# If Norjak were but a stage illusion, how would you have done it?

Tags: history, magic

I am not certain this is the right site for this post: rather than your analysis of an *actual* trick of stage magic, I invite you to reconsider the [hijacking of Flight NOA 305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper) ("Norjak") under the *unproven assumption* it was actually a feat of escapology. Please comment if you find this out of place & I will delete the post.

Several details of the timeline suggest the perpetrator, "Dan Cooper", understood at least the basic principles of stage magic. According to WP, which reflects the consensus description of the incident, he showed reliance on misdirection at least once: by demanding 4 parachutes he dissuaded the police from sabotaging them, as this opened the possibility he would make an hostage jump with him. He may have known the craft could not fly to Mexico as he demanded and feigned to let the pilots & police settle for Reno on their own; *etc.*

AFAIK this perspective has not been suggested in print before; again, your comment is welcome if you know better or if you think this [href to the WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper#Hijacking) is not enough & I should repeat it here.

So my question is: **in the shoes of "Dan Cooper" and w/o any experience in skydiving, how would you remove yourself and $200,000 in cash from Flight 305, back on Nov. 24, 1971?**

Your resources:

- a Boeing 727 aircraft in 1971 config: ventral staircase w/o ["D. B. Cooper vane"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_vane), no peephole on the access door to the cockpit *etc.*;
- you know the actual timeline and route in advance, including how much time to refuel in Seattle and 2nd leg of the trip to Reno in stead of Mexico;
- your plan *may* rely on being given functional chutes; however you must survive your fall $\ \ge 5$yrs if [unbeknownst to everyone, one was actually dummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper#Subsequent_FBI_disclosures). Note that even with proper gear that "Dan Cooper" apparently lacked, professional skydivers still consider the move suicidal;
- as much clandestine preparations in Reno as you need; all complete before the flight takes off from Portland, though;
- you may camouflage any unlikely item as the "bomb" if it fits in the briefcase: only a terror-stricken hostess will ever have a glimpse of it and certainly not be looking for a proof it is ready to explode. My personal favorite is a transponder & bars of cushioning foam, finally dropped together with the ransom;
- $\ \le 1$ stooge among the crew; however, you may not communicate with him from Portland on (this excludes the female crew members) & you must assume all of their luggage will be searched in Reno; moreover, you must assume he is under constant watch during the whole hijacking;
- $\ \le 1$ passenger stooge, whose role is to leave some hand luggage behind in Seattle; however, your stooge must still have $\ \ge 1$  piece of luggage in hand and it will be searched when they disembark in Seattle;
- you may dispose of $\ \le 250$ kg through the open staircase; however you must explain how the missing mass went unnoticed and, if you declined to be part of it (see above), how *you* went unnoticed in Reno;
- you are not required to retrieve the ransom in the end if you opted to dispose of it in flight, not even to plan for future retrieval; nor to arrange for [3 bundles of notes to pop up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper#Recovered_ransom_money) 10yrs later.

**(Edited after Weather Vane's fascinating answer)**
Note the above requirements are my choice, not exactly the actual circumstances; they are s/what more relaxed, *e. g.* you are allowed to sneak a load of ~150kg on board in addition of what the FBI believed was present in Portland; you need not even *intend* to retrieve the money, nor make some notes from it appear later.
On the other hand, I opted that previous skydiving experience does not help you (other than in planning your show) because skydiving experts said *they* would not dare the jump, even with adequate gear not kwown to be available to "Dan Cooper".

You need a stooge among the crew if you want to store props in the luggage hold; you must also explain how to access it from the passenger area (in 1971) and how you did it w/o signalling your move to the cockpit.

Acceptable answers *must* provide proof they are compatible with all the known facts. They *may* put the life of the hijacker at notable risk, *not* mean certain death: assume he had no training in parachuting and prove he reasonably survived your scenario $\ge 5$yrs, in spite of choosing 1  malfunctioning chute out of 2.

**(Skip this if it might be an unwelcome spoiler. )**
For what it's worth, the baseline of my pet solution is, do not try to *definitely* convince Law Enforcement you jumped; all you need is they *expect* it during the search of the aircraft in Reno, when their priority is to join the crew & comfort them. By the time a minute search commences, you are far away or maybe helping the FBI with it, unloading the hold in a suitable disguise under their supervision.

It relies on hypothetical features of the Boeing 727 I have no means to confirm or reject, so I would not accept it as an answer.

Comment: You might like to post this on [SE Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), where the format needs a 'notable claim' with references. For example a well know media outlet claiming that the 'stunt' was a stage illusion. Does this post have a 'correct answer' or is it speculation dressed up as a game/puzzle?

Comment: @Weather Vane What claims they deem notable is still a touchy issue. The baseline is: the claim must be widely believed to be true whereas, in the present case, the claim does not even seem to have been expressed.

Comment: What I meant, is if the topic could be *reframed* to be suitable for [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

My answer is: **Probably not.**

---

**The weight**

There is a misquoted fact in the OP: the weight that needed to be disposed of was nowhere near the 250 kg claimed here. The WP article says

> FBI agents pushing a 200-pound (91 kg) sled out of the open airstair . . .

Consider that \$200,000 in \$20 bills weighs only 10 kg, and Cooper is described as being "170 to 180 lbs" (say 80 kg), plus a parachute of around 10 kg, plus the bag and the attache case: total perhaps 110 kg.

Although having less weight to dispose of would have made an illusion easier to manage.

---

**The parachutes**

Another account differs about "four parachutes".
From a WP footnote, [Crime Museum - D.B. Cooper](https://www.crimemuseum.org/crime-library/cold-cases/d-b-cooper/) says:

> Schaffner recalled that the handwritten ink note demanded \$200,000 in cash and two sets of parachutes.

Each set consists of a main chute and a reserve chute, hence "four parachutes".

As the money only weighed 10 kg (and he could have thrown the attache case out) he only needed one parachute. Sending the money down with another parachute would have risked being separated from the money, after dark.

Requesting an extra parachute *was* a good piece of misdirection, agreed, perhaps intended to confuse that he might take a hostage with him, and also because Cooper knew he would need extra cord.

The money was delivered "in a knapsack" but you can't easily wear a parachute and a knapsack. That's perhaps why Cooper needed the other chute: for a good amount of cord to secure the bag, and to dangle it from his waist.

There is a common way of mis-thinking that there is *one* reason for doing something ~ either Cooper needed the materials, *or* it was misdirection. But *both* reasons made it a good plan.

---

**Contents of the attache case**

Accounts differ as to what was in the case. The WP article states

> Cooper opened his briefcase long enough for her to glimpse **eight** red cylinders.

and the other article I linked states

> He opened his suitcase wide enough for her to get a glimpse of wires and **two cylinders**, potentially dynamite sticks.

There was probably no bomb. Cooper knew his bluff would not be called – it only had to look like a bomb, and he only allowed them a glimpse. So what *was* in the bag? I suggest that any misdirection wasn't to stage a disappearing trick, but to conceal footwear, a jump suit, and possibly a helmet (see below).

---

**Inexperienced skydiver**

The FBI concluded that Cooper wasn't an experienced skydiver.

> No experienced parachutist would have jumped in the pitch-black night, in the rain, with a 172 mph [77 m/s] wind in his face wearing loafers and a trench coat. It was simply too risky. He also missed that his reserve parachute was only for training and had been sewn shut, something a skilled skydiver would have checked.

Funnily enough, the dummy parachute was allegedly supplied "by mistake", even though it is claimed that it would be obvious to an expert. Yet they were obtained from a skydiving school, presumably from such experts.

So it might not have been so obvious to Cooper either, and maybe he only noticed (if at all) *after* he had butchered the intact parachute set. If the expert who supplied the chutes didn't notice, that isn't a good reason to suppose that Cooper could not have been an experienced skydiver.

But anyway, it was the reserve chute that was sewn up, not the main chute.

Cooper was evidently knowledgeable about flying and that type of plane. His plan was worked out in advance, he was cool, and it seems unlikely that the escape would be so risky as to not know how to skydive.

I also wonder why he chose an afternoon flight – it only departed about 3 hours before sunset. Even without the delay refuelling, Cooper must have known that he would be jumping in the dark, and so that must have been *part of the plan*. So that he could not be tracked to the ground.

He seems to have known exactly what he was doing, and enough about skydiving that it would be inadvisable to jump after dark without experience. He even knew what *type* of parachute he wanted: civilian, not military.

So contrary to what the FBI (later) decided, I propose that Cooper *must* have been an expert skydiver, and he came prepared with adequate weather protection.

---

**The money found**

The package of money found must have been buried deliberately – that was researched quite thoroughly, and it was definitely part of the ransom cash. So did Cooper bury it, or someone else?

If Cooper hid it:

- He survived the jump, and hid small amounts of money in different places, or
- He staged an illusion, threw out the money and continued to Reno, and returned later to find and bury it, or
- He took the money to Reno, and returned to the site to bury some of it.

If someone else found the money and hid it:

- If Cooper had staged an illusion and continued to Reno, he must have thrown the money out, or
- If Cooper had jumped, he may have perished, or
- If Cooper had jumped, the bag might have burst and the money scattered and he lost some of it.

In none of those scenarios is it credible that Cooper escaped at Reno airport.

Why was there one \$20 bill missing? When Cooper reached the ground, he composed himself, and he lit a cigarette, or even a fire to warm up. How? He ripped open one pack of money, folded a \$20 bill into a spill (taper), and lit it – his moment of triumph.

---

One thing that does seem strange to me, is the uncertainty of the location where Cooper jumped. The crew knew exactly *when* he jumped – they noticed the weight distribution change. The plane was being shadowed by two military aircraft, and apparently neither of *them* (or their controllers) knew their precise location / route?

Why was no other money ever traced? Either Cooper died before he could spend it (perhaps during the escape), or he realised the notes would be traceable and it was too risky to spend. But he had pulled it off and his "grudge" was satisfied, so did he care?

---

In conclusion, I would take it in quite the opposite direction. It was suspected that Cooper might be (ex) military. So, far from being an inexperienced skydiver who made the stupid mistake of jumping out at night in street clothes (or staging it to make others think so) – that he not only knew what he was doing but had been *trained for it*. Trained to jump at night, trained how to survive in the wild (part of his hidden kit) and trained how to make his way out unseen. There were no unknowns or bad risks. The attache case would have been strong enough to contain the money and survive a hard landing (the supplied bag would be an unknown), and every last detail would have been worked out in advance.

Comment: I do not claim the craft was lighter by 250 kg in Reno. I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Not to minimize the astuteness of your analysis, I will not accept it for missing the main point: the OP is not how "D. B. Cooper" did it, it is how *you*, a stage magician w/o experience in skydiving, would have done it in the actual circumstances of the hijacking and with 1971 technology.

Comment: There another flaw in the FBI's reasoning in *"The FBI stressed that inclusion of the dummy reserve parachute, one of four obtained in haste from a Seattle skydiving school, was accidental."* Since Cooper is claimed to have used that parachute set, and it wasn't found, how could the FBI have known it was supplied by mistake? And someone didn't even realise that there were two *sets* of parachutes, not four separate parachutes.

Comment: If there was any illusion, IMO it wasn't to escape in Reno (the money found rules that out), but to make it *thought* that he could not have survived the jump and the wilderness, but did have the necessary skills. There wasn't a defective parachute: only the reserve chute, which apparently needs to be deployed in only 1 jump in 1000. If Cooper noticed the unusable reserve chute, perhaps he used that set to reinforce the illusion that he must have perished (which he might have too). I am more expecting the question to be closed, than the answer accepted, but it was interesting to study.

Comment: The location the money was found makes it plausible the ransom was dropped in flight thru the aft stairs; this does not imply nor exclude the hijacker jumped with it. Thanks for your attention; as I said, I am not sure if my post is really on-topic.

Comment: IMO thoroughly *im*plausible that Cooper threw out the money in the dark in the middle of nowhere and continued to Reno. Not even the crew could be sure exactly where they were, never mind Cooper or any accomplice on the ground. The first GPS tracking devices weren't available until 1978, and that was only a trial.